# Need help in Android View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Okay, i'm creating a simple view pager where you can swipe between different fragments. i have used PagerAdapter to be able to swipe between these fragment.

Now how do i get rid of these black highlight thing that appears when i try to swipe to an empty position. (See in picture)

[image]

Any codes that i need to put in the viewpager?
Please make the code simple as possible for me so its clear to understand.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use android attribute for view pager below:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

it will hide the fading edge when you over scroll the contents.

Comment: Thanks! it worked! I was doing some stupid things to get rid of it in java. never figured out the xml part :D